# Suddenly my api_view is not defined. Why?

Tags: python, django

I am making a webpage using React frontend and Django backend. I have trouble running my backend because things supposedly aren't defined. E.g. I get this message when trying to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

getting error,

```
name 'api_view' is not defined
```

What can I do to fix it?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .serializers import UserSerializer

def homePageView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

# 
@api_view(['POST'])
def createUserView(request):
    # Create a new user 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create serializer with data from new user object
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data) #datafeltet inneholder json fra frontend, se eks. nederst
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Save user
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    #return HttpResponse('User')
```

Comment: Please take the effort to paste the code here

Comment: Check if you have imported it or not in your ```views.py```

Comment: @Sujay, I tried but it turned out really wierd

Comment: @IngridGomo You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should import the `api_view` decorator as follows:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
```

Please verify that you are using the correct virtual environment, and ensure that the rest_framework is installed by running pip freeze.

Comment: Like this? "from rest_framework.decorators import api_view". Then it gets underlined, and I get this message: "Import "rest_framework.decorators" could not be resolved. PylancereportMissingImports)"

Comment: Make sure that you are using correct virtual env, you can verify `rest_framework` is installed or not using `pip freeze`.

Comment: I do not completely know what a virtual environment is. How do I verify that rest_framework is installed? What is pip freeze? I am using it, and if so, should I stop?

Comment: Go to command line and execute `pip freeze` and show us output.

Comment: Thanks, I got this:
asgiref==3.3.4
Django==3.1.8
djangorestframework==3.12.4
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1

Comment: @IngridGomo edit your question add copy paste code over there, so we can help you.

Comment: I think it works now! Many of the things are still undefined, but I was able to run backend now. Don't know why some things must be defined, and other don't, but oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To install the rest_framework use`pip install djangorestframework`

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me when I input into views.py file: --
"from rest_framework.decorators import api_view"